# How to detect if an app is installed (without URI scheme)?

Tags: ios, cordova, ngcordova

Let's say I have launched an app on iOS app store.

I have a couple of details, like app ID, wildcard, etc.

How can I determine, preferably using Cordova/Phonegap, whether this app has been installed on my device?

There is a cordova plugin that allows you to do this, bit it requires a custom URI scheme as input.

Link: ngCordova/appAvailability

However, this requires that you register your custom scheme. What if you haven't defined it?

Is there a way to get it quickly?

Comment: I am 90% certain that this isn't possible but have to admit to being behind on the area. So let's see. But if nobody can answer then that's probably why.

Comment: @tommy Perhaps retrieving a list of all the apps installed?

Comment: I am 100% certain that this isn't possible.  You will need to add a custom URL scheme to your app

Comment: @JohnAndrews iOS doesn't expose any such list. It's outside of your app's sandbox.